# Parsing Buffered Bytes into Integers with sscanf - C

Tags: c, parsing

I am receiving Serial commands, and I would like to be able to parse out data from between the comas.  An example, would be `"SET,1,3,1"` and then be able to parse out the `1,3,1` as integers.  After doing some reading I tried to accomplish this with a `sscanf`, but when I monitor the variables, they are not being set properly.

Here is my code:

```
if (strncmp(command_buf, "SET,1,3,1", 9) == 0) {

              u32_t port_number;
              u32_t pin_number;
              u32_t logic_level;

              sscanf(command_buf + 4, "%u,%u,%u", &port_number, &pin_number, &logic_level);
            }
```

I have also tried this for example, but the variable is `0`

```
u32_t port_number = command_buf[5];
```

Comment: You initially said `sscanf` and the question was different

Comment: Are you sure you're using scanf?  It should be sscanf (note the extra s).

Comment: Sorry, yes I've changed my question with `sscanf`

Comment: What is the type of u32_t?  %u will parse unsigned ints.

Comment: u32_t is an unsigned long

Comment: Check return value of sscanf.

Comment: Also, enable compiler warnings and see if it warns about scanf format string.

Comment: @hyde.: These questions tend to vary in answer..someone writes something - it is contextual but still it is not right because question is moving from one snapshot to another. Just saying - from Q/A we tend towars debugging

Comment: Yes the return value from `sscanf` is 3 as expected

Comment: "u32_t is an unsigned long " then %u is incorrect.  You should be using %lu as the answer given suggests.

Comment: in C, array indexing starts with 0, not 1 so this statement: `u32_t port_number = command_buf[5];`  will extract a `comma` not the port number `1`

Comment: rather than using some 'home grown' type like: `u32_t`,  suggest using the types defined in `stdint.h`  (which would be: `uint32_t`

Comment: per the posted code, the program already knows exactly what the input string looks like, so why bother using `sscanf()`, just 'hardcode' the values into the variables

Comment: why use a 'unsigned long' variable to input a single digit value?

Answer (score 2):

```
sscanf(command_buf + 4, "%lu,%lu,%lu", &port_number, &pin_number, &logic_level);
```

You just need to parse the input string like this. This would work. ([`u32_t` is 32 bit `unsigned long`](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~svb/oslab/Minix/usr/include/sys/types.h)).

You can do it using `sscanf`. Because you wanted to parse from string not a  stream.

Also you should check the return value of `sscanf` to check whether it is getting the inputs right.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try, although I'm getting a warning from the compiler: `implicit declaration of function 'sscanf' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]`

Comment: @user1574598.: Use the proper header. `stdio.h`.

Comment: You haven't included the header then.  That will screw things up tremendously.

Comment: @user1574598 each time you see "implicit declaration of ...." consider it as an error.

Comment: Ah, thanks.  I've included the header and got rid of the error, but the variable values are not giving me anything meaningful.

Comment: @user1574598.: How did you print it? or check it>

Comment: I'm actually using CrossStudio - I am watching the variables in a watch list

Comment: But it parses and gives the correct result along with return value of 3. Maybe you are lookng at wrong point.